# Flex timer delay changer?

Tags: apache-flex, timer

I need help with the following...

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(x);
```

basically x is an array...

when `timer.start()` is invoked

it runs, the first count is 1000 ms, then the second 800 ms, and the third 6200 ms and so on. In other words, it's a dynamic change in the delay and not a continuous delay of x ms.

How can this be done? Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timer.start();
function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void
{
   timer.stop();
   if (timer.currentCount == 1) {
      timer.delay = 800;
   } else if (timer.currentCount == 2) {
      timer.delay = 6200;
   } else {
      //other conditions
   }
   timer.start();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked great, I changed it to a for loop because I have hundreds of delays.

Answer (score 1):

What @package said is right. Based on your comment saying you have hundreds of delays, this would be better code.

```
var delays:Array=[1000, 500, 6200, ...];
var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timer.start();
function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
   timer.stop();
   timer.delay = delays[timer.currentCount-1];
   timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much cleaner. I changed timer.currentCount to (timer.currentCount-1) because it was skipping the index 0 of the array.